# How can i find the Percentage of each element for the sum of the array? c#

Tags: c#, arrays, percentage

I need to find the percentage of each value in an array in concerning the sum of the array.

I am having the user input data in to an array 24 times, containing the number of cars seen, once input, then list each array element and an try and find its percentage of the sum of the array.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] trafficCount;
        const int hours = 24;
        Traffic traff = new Traffic();
        traff.Report();
    }
    public Traffic()
    {
         trafficCount = new int[hours + 1];
    }
    public void showData()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        int maxValue = trafficCount.Max();
        int maxIndex = trafficCount.ToList().IndexOf(maxValue);
        int sum = trafficCount.Sum();
        Console.WriteLine("Traffic Report");
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------");
        int percent = maxValue/sum*100 ;


        Console.WriteLine("{0}{1,24}", "Hour", "\tNumber of vehicles  Percent");
        for (int hour = 0; hour < trafficCount.Length; hour++)

            Console.WriteLine("{0,5}{1,24}", hour, trafficCount[hour]);              Console.Write("\t"+percent);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

calculation of percentage of #cars in a given hour per day is shown by expression: `(double)trafficCount[hour]/vehicleTotal` below in the loop. In order for it to work you need to get the `vehicleTotal` which you already had computed across whole `trafficCount[]` array before running the output.

```
public class Traffic
{
    private int[] trafficCount;

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Traffic traff = new Traffic(24);
        traff.showData();
    }
    public Traffic(int hours)
    {
        trafficCount = new int[hours];
        // populate with dummy data
        for (int i = 0; i < hours; i++)
        {
            trafficCount[i] = i*2+1; // replace this with real data
        }
    }

    public void showData()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Traffic Report");
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------");

        long vehicleTotal = trafficCount.Sum();

        Console.WriteLine("{0}{1,24}", "Hour", "\tNumber of vehicles  Percent");
        for (int hour = 0; hour < trafficCount.Length; hour++)
        {
            var percentageInHour = (double)trafficCount[hour]/ vehicleTotal;
            Console.WriteLine("{0,5}{1,12}{2,17:P}", hour, trafficCount[hour], percentageInHour);
        }
    }
}
```

the output based on dummy data is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution:

The program

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TrafficScanner scanner = new TrafficScanner(5);
        scanner.Read();

        TrafficReport trafficReport = new TrafficReport(scanner.Vehicles);
        trafficReport.Print();
    }
}
```

`TrafficScanner` keeps track of all the vehicles travelling per hour. It lasts for certain number of `hours`.

```
public class TrafficScanner
{
    private int[] vehiclesPerHour;

    public TrafficScanner(int hours)
    {
        vehiclesPerHour = new int[hours];
    }

    public void Read()
    {
        int hour = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            if (input == "") break;

            int carsThisHours = 0;

            bool isParsedSuccessfully = Int32.TryParse(input, out carsThisHours);
            if (isParsedSuccessfully)
            {
                vehiclesPerHour[hour++] += carsThisHours;
                hour = hour % vehiclesPerHour.Length;
            }
        }
    }

    public int[] Vehicles
    {
        get
        {
            return vehiclesPerHour;
        }
    }
}
```

`TrafficReport` prints the statistics of the traffic vehicles. It prepares the data used in the report.

```
public class TrafficReport
{
    private int[] vehiclesPerHour;
    private double[] trafficPercentage;

    public TrafficReport(int[] vehicles)
    {
        vehiclesPerHour = vehicles;
    }

    public void Print()
    {
        PrepareData();
        ShowData();
    }

    private void PrepareData()
    {
        int numberOfVehicles = vehiclesPerHour.Sum();

        trafficPercentage = new double[vehiclesPerHour.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < vehiclesPerHour.Length; ++i)
        {
            trafficPercentage[i] = ((double) vehiclesPerHour[i]) / numberOfVehicles;
        }
    } 

    private void ShowData()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Traffic Report");
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------");


        Console.WriteLine("{0}{1,24}", "Hour", "\tNumber of vehicles  Percent");
        for (int hour = 0; hour < trafficPercentage.Length; ++hour)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0,3}{1,14}{2,18:P}", hour, vehiclesPerHour[hour], trafficPercentage[hour]);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An improved version

Main Program

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TrafficScanner scanner = new TrafficScanner(5);
    scanner.Read();

    VehiclePercentages percentages = new VehiclePercentages(scanner.Vehicles); 

    TrafficReport trafficReport = new TrafficReport(scanner.Vehicles, percentages.Values);
    trafficReport.Print();
}
```

TrafficScanner (same as before)

```
public class TrafficScanner
{
    private int[] vehiclesPerHour;

    public TrafficScanner(int hours)
    {
        vehiclesPerHour = new int[hours];
    }

    public void Read()
    {
        int hour = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            if (input == "") break;

            int carsThisHours = 0;

            bool isParsedSuccessfully = Int32.TryParse(input, out carsThisHours);
            if (isParsedSuccessfully)
            {
                vehiclesPerHour[hour++] += carsThisHours;
                hour = hour % vehiclesPerHour.Length;
            }
        }
    }

    public int[] Vehicles
    {
        get
        {
            return vehiclesPerHour;
        }
    }
}
```

`VehiclePercentages` was extracted from `TrafficReport`. The idea is to have independent code, focused on one thing only. The purpose of `VehiclePercentages` is computing the car percentage for each hour.

```
public class VehiclePercentages
{
    private double[] trafficPercentages;

    public VehiclePercentages(int[] vehiclesPerHour)
    {
        int numberOfVehicles = vehiclesPerHour.Sum();

        trafficPercentages = new double[vehiclesPerHour.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < vehiclesPerHour.Length; ++i)
        {
            trafficPercentages[i] = ((double)vehiclesPerHour[i]) / numberOfVehicles;
        }
    }

    public double[] Values
    {
        get
        {
            return trafficPercentages;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, `TrafficReport` does one thing only. It prints the traffic data with the required format. It doesn't have to bother anymore how to get the required data.

```
public class TrafficReport
{
    private int[] vehicles;
    private double[] percentages;

    public TrafficReport(int[] vehiclesPerHour, double[] trafficPercentages)
    {
        vehicles = vehiclesPerHour;
        percentages = trafficPercentages;
    }

    public void Print()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Traffic Report");
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------");


        Console.WriteLine("{0}{1,24}", "Hour", "\tNumber of vehicles  Percent");
        for (int hour = 0; hour < percentages.Length; ++hour)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0,3}{1,14}{2,18:P}", hour, vehicles[hour], percentages[hour]);
        }
    }
}
```